# How to setup Jenkins for Multiple Jobs for the same git repository

Tags: git, jenkins, version-control

( I m not a DevOps/SCM )

We currently use Subversion and are in the process of migrating to git.

Our project has multiple areas and currently each area is set up as an independent job in our Jenkins.

1. If we migrate svn to git, how many times will Jenkins do a git pull? Will it pull the same repository for each job independently?
2. If the developer makes a change and pushes it to the repository, which job will get triggered? ( IOW, how will Jenkins know that the change belongs to JobA and *not* jobB )

Any help will be much appreciated

--sony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your SVN to Git migration result in one giant monorepo, then yes, Jenkins would pull from the same Git repository, one per Jenkins job.

You could then try and make sure the [Jenkins job only triggers  for particular directory commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48994953/6309).

But the best practice is to split your SVN repository into *several* Git repositories (one per "area"), allowing a finer-grained control when it comes to Jenkins.